# How to set a cache with Local Storage

Tags: javascript, caching, local-storage, session-cookies

I have a ads box and i want close it to by clicking x button so after it has been closed i don't want to se it until 24 hours with cache I created a localstorage but it's not working as i expected how should i edit my example

```js
    var showCase = Math.round(+new Date() / 1000);

        document.getElementById("close_ads").addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (typeof localStorage.showCase == 'undefined' || parseInt(localStorage.showCase) <= (showCase - 3600)) {            
          localStorage.showCase = showCase;
          document.getElementById('reklam_box').style.display = 'none';
        }
        });
```

```html
<div id="ads_box">
Hi..I am a ads..
<span id="close_ads">Close ads and don't show unit for 24 hours</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ads_box">
        Hi..I am a ads..
        <span id="close_ads">Close ads and don't show unit for 24 hours</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        var dontShowUntil = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);

        document.getElementById("close_ads").addEventListener("click", function () {
            localStorage.dontShowUntil = dontShowUntil;
            document.getElementById('ads_box').style.display = 'none';
        });

        if (new Date(localStorage.dontShowUntil) > new Date()) {
            document.getElementById('ads_box').style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Localstorages `.setItem()` and `.getItem` check this out.

https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

So something like this

```
// set the item
localStorage.setItem('showCase', 3600);

//get the item
var showCase = localStorage.getItem('showCase');
```

Comment: hmm..so how can i provide to display:none after click to x button with localstorage my english is not enough to understand article thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

useful linkes:

https://johnresig.com/blog/dom-storage/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

NOTICE : when working with localStorage with array of objects you must save it like that:

Just convert the objects to JSON strings:

```
localStorage.setItem("savedData", JSON.stringify(objects));

var objects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedData")));
```